# SQL Query to return data based on last date recorded by item and by Client

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Data Sample]

From the attached data sample I need to create an sql query in order to return the latest transaction for that account and that particular code. i.e the query should return as follows ;

The last price of 60.00 was recorded for account S494 and code 5044 on the 24/10/2016. This will identify when last the client bought this item and at which price.

Comment: You should not be storing `DATE` values as `VARCHAR`...  store them as the correct type - it makes these types of queries not a royal pain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use RANK() to partition and select the range you require (in this case you need the top 1, so where RANK() is 1 - but you can amend the where clause accordingly).

You could just use ROW_NUMBER() instead, but you might have multiple records where trandate is the same, so you need both records where RANK() is 1 (using the data in your example - if this will never be the case use ROW_NUMBER).

```
SELECT [code], [account], [price], [trandate]
FROM
 ( SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [account], [code] ORDER BY [trandate] DESC) [rank], [code], [account], [price], [trandate] FROM [#trans] ) [d]
WHERE [d].[rank] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie for your help. At first glance the query is returning the desired results, however I am not able to save the query as an sql view for future use. Is it possible to save such in an SQL view ?

Comment: You should be able to save it as a view, CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View] AS <insert query here> should do it for you no problem. Feel free to raise another question and link it here if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Jamie,  View created successfully as indicated above. Many thanks for your help and wish you all a Happy New Year !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT code,
  account,
  price,
  trandate
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,
    row_number() over (partition BY account, code order by convert(datetime,trandate,103) DESC) rn
  FROM your_table
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select TOP 1 CODE,ACCOUNT,PRICE,TRANSDATE
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY CAST(TRANSDATE AS DATE) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however this query in my real table only returned the last product bought by this client which happened to be today. My query is for every item the client bought , when was the last date purchased and at which price. Thanks

Comment: Can you please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and  future readers both if you can add more information in your post.